# Accessing sessions from another method

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
get '/blackjack/*' do
  if params[:splat] == "/hit" and defined? session[:bj_game]
    erb :blackjack
  elsif params[:splat] == "/fold" and defined? session[:bj_game]
    session[:bj_hum].fold = true
    erb :blackjack
  else
    if defined? session[:bj_game]
      new_session_check
      score_check
      erb :blackjack
    else
      session[:bj_game] = false
      session[:score] = 0
      new_session_check
      score_check
      erb :blackjack
    end
  end
end

def new_session_check
  if session[:bj_game] == false
    session[:bj_hum] = Blackjack.new
    session[:bj_com] = Blackjack.new
    session[:bj_game] = true
  end
end

def score_check
  if session[:bj_hum].game_loop == false
    if session[:bj_hum].score.to_i > 0
      session[:score] += session[:bj_hum].score.to_i
      check_save(session[:score])
    else
      session[:score] = 0
    end
    session[:bj_game] = false
    session[:bj_hum] = Blackjack.new
    session[:bj_com] = Blackjack.new
  end
end
```

Whenever it gets to score check, I get NoMethodError - Undefined method 'game_loop' for NilClass.

However, if I start from the main page:

```
get '/' do
  session[:bj_game] = false
  session[:score] = 0
  erb :home
end
```

And click on the link to /blackjack from the home erb, it will work as the new_session_check saw that the variable was false and then created new instances of the Blackjack class(which does have attr_accessor for game_loop).

Why does it not register in the get '/blackjack' version?

http://pastebin.com/6EFpp5gh - Here is a mockup version you can run to verify this. First go to localhost:4567/blackjack and you will get an internal service error. Restart the server then go to localhost:4567 first and then localhost:4567/blackjack afterward and you will see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers):

```
get 'somepath' do
  score_check
end

helpers do
  def score_check
    # now you can access session from within here
  end
end
```

Comment: Was hoping that would work but same thing. I go to http://localhost:4567/blackjack/ manually and get an Internal Server Error with the same thing, but if I click on <a href="/blackjack" title="Blackjack">Blackjack</a> from '/', it'll work.

Comment: I made this mockup version that has the same error: http://pastebin.com/6EFpp5gh run it, then go directly to localhost:4567/blackjack/ it will get an internal server error, then restart it and go to localhost:4567 and then to localhost:4567/blackjack/ it won't get that error.